# What actually happened with Diavolo?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

At the final battle between Giorno and Diavolo in episode 38. Diavolo got punched many times, and almost drowned in the river.

He survived that and able to catch the edge of the sewer stairs, which kept his body floating. Poorly, he met a burglar/homeless man that stabbed him, and then he lost consciousness. Just after that, he looks like he's in a hospital bed, and a female doctor suddenly performs an autopsy on his body while Diavolo's alive. In the middle of the autopsy he suddenly teleports to a downtown area where he gets hit by a car, and last, he met with a child and for no reason Diavolo got scared.

What happens to Diavolo in episode 38 exactly? According to [Jojo's Wiki](https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/Gold_Experience_Requiem),
such stated

> Gold Experience Requiem is a close-range Requiem Stand that boasts an
> incredible increase in both speed and power compared to its previous
> form. It also wields the arcane power of reverting anything to "zero",
> effectively undoing their actions; a power that trumps even the time
> erasure/nullification of King Crimson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understood from the show was that Giorno's Gold Experience Requiem put Diavolo in a state where he constantly had to experience death over and over again forever. He would die in a particular scenario, wake up in another place and experience his death in that place as well and then proceed to wake up in another place... and so on. From the Diavolo page of the [Jojo wiki](https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/Diavolo#History) under the section Final Moments, it is stated that

> Due to the ability of Gold Experience Requiem, Diavolo is trapped in
>   an infinite death loop; He continues to experience death over and over
>   for eternity due to dying and subsequently returning to point zero
>   (before his death), starting with drowning in the nearby river,
>   followed by being stabbed to death, autopsied alive, and hit by a car.
>   Panicked in anticipation for where the next source of his never-ending
>   fatality is going to come from, the last of what is seen of Diavolo is
>   him begging a harmless child to get away from him.

Comment: Following that. He never hit the truth of well, death, which caused the infinite death loop. He never actually "dies". He still has to experience the pain, but he'll never really die.